# Beginner coder checking if input is part of a cycle?

Tags: graph, nodes, cycle, edges

```
public Graph (int nb){
    this.nbNodes = nb;
    this.adjacency = new boolean [nb][nb];
    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nb; j++){
            this.adjacency[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
}

public void addEdge (int i, int j){
    if(!(i<0 || i>=this.nbNodes|| j<0 || j>=this.nbNodes))
    {
        this.adjacency[i][j] = true;
        this.adjacency[j][i] = true;
    }
}

public void removeEdge (int i, int j){
    if(!(i<0 || i>=this.nbNodes|| j<0 || j>=this.nbNodes))
    {
        this.adjacency[i][j] = false;
        this.adjacency[j][i] = false;
    }
}

public int nbEdges(){

    int c =0;
    for(int i=0; i<this.nbNodes; i++)
    {
        for(int j= 0; j<this.nbNodes; j++)
        {
            if(this.adjacency[i][j]==true)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    return c/2;
}

public boolean cycle(int start){

    return false;
}
```

A Graph has a number of nodes nbNodes and is characterized by its adjacency matrix adjacency. adjacency[i][j] states whether or not there is an edge from the i-th node to the j-th node.
the graphs are undirected.

I am a beginner coder and am having trouble writing cycle(int start)

It takes as input an integer, g.cycle(i) returns true if the i-th node is part of a cycle (and false otherwise).

does anyone have any idea on how I should approach this?